# Error when dump JSON data to mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

How to fixed error "how to fix invalid character 'x' in string escape code by py mongo"? [My error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk5OG.png)

Comment: Something in your data has an escape code that isn't handled. Find the record, find the problem.

Comment: It would be easier to understand your problem if you posted your error message as text instead of an image. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

Check your BSON packet where there is X in it, you can query for the value x using the mongo find command if you already have in other mongo instance, it clearly shows it imported 14k records but some records can't be imported because of incompatible format. The solution query the db and find the error documents and remove it.

Comment: but, my data record = 1 bilion data, how to find and remove that? can you help me? and what about the other solution?

Comment: make aggregation for the specific error and make and save it